# Iptables drop access to specific ip address except from my ip

Tags: iptables, router, dd-wrt

I've got a dd-wrt router running and I want to block access to a wireless printer from all ip addresses except from the ip addresses that are allowed.
let's say my printer's ip is 192.168.1.101 and my ip is 192.168.1.102.
I can drop all requests to my printer using the following rule

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.1.101 -j DROP
```

but how can I allow access to this ip from my ip address without negating all of my other iptables?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the rules would be done on the INPUT or OUTPUT chains.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 128.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.101 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -d 192.168.1.101 -j DROP
```

You need to order your rules so that your accept traffic before you drop traffic.  Rules are evaluated in order.  If you use a closed by default policy, the second rule above is unnecessary.